# VSCode - Automatically Create Matching CSS files

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

## **Problem**

I am currently create a React web app and I am creating my own components that also have their own CSS files. Currently I have to create a matching CSS file everytime I create a component. I was hoping for something sort of how like when you create a project in Visual Studio is will create a .aspx page as well as a .cs file along with it.

My current structure is `../src/components/DashNav.js` and the matching stylesheet would be `../src/styles/components/DashNav.scss`

## **Question**

Does anyone know if there is a way to trigger a creation of a new file each time a js file is created?

If not, is there any extensions that anyone would recommend? I have already seen [VSCODE Create File Folder](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-create-file-folder) but that doesn't do me really any good since I can just do this in the terminal.

Comment: I don't think an extension exists for such specific task, but you can create one yourself, should be simple enough. VSCode extension are created using TS, you work with React so I guess you might know some typescript

Comment: When you create your JS file along with that create .CSS file manually!

Answer (score 1):

[Folder Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Huuums.vscode-fast-folder-structure#folderTemplates.fileTemplates) is the extension that I'm using for this right now. Here is how I've set up my folder structure and and file templates in `settings.json`

```
  "folderTemplates.structures": [
    {
      "name": "My Custom Template",
      "omitParentDirectory": true,
      "structure": [
        {
          "fileName": "<FTName>.js",
          "template": "React Functional Component"
        },
        {
          "fileName": "<FTName>.module.css",
          "template": "CSS Module"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "folderTemplates.fileTemplates": {
    "React Functional Component": [
      "import styles from '<FTName>.module.css';",
      "",
      "export const <FTName> = (props) => {",
      "  return <div></div>;",
      "};"
    ],
    "CSS Module": ".<FTName | lowercase> {}"
  }
```